# Storing multiple sessions in Memcache for a user

Tags: authentication, memcached, access-token

I am storing temporary session tokens in Memcache and it works well. When a user logs into my application they present their credentials and a token is stored in Memcache with a 15 minute TTL and also returned to the user. Each time the user makes a request presenting the token its TTL gets extended. The Memcache key is "user-id-{id}". This means that if a user logs in twice their first session will be invalidated as the token is replaced.

I would like for users to have the ability to have multiple active tokens. The reason I use the "user-id-{id}" key name instead of a randomly generated string is because I want to control the number of active tokens a user has. If I gave them random names a single user could fill up my Memcache DB by generating millions of tokens.

How can I limit them to having, say, 10 active tokens? I considered adding an index like "user-id-{id}-{index}" and then iterating over 1-10 for the index to see if there is an empty space for a token. This feels like a lot of work and has some race conditions. Are there better options for achieving my goal if I want to continue using Memcache?

Answer (score 0):

Keep the same key and store a collection of active sessions. If you do this you'll need to manually manage the TTLs for all but the first entry.

Comment: but then they would all share one entry in memcache and could not have separate TTLs

Comment: yeah, good point @william. I should have had something about it in my answer. I updated my answer. having to worry about the TTLs yourself does make the solution less attractive. that said, it may be the best that you can come up with.